# Flash player updates: auto-updating shuts off by itself

Tags: mac, security, flash, updates

I have observed on various Macs running El Capitan that although the update setting for flash player "Allow Adobe to install updates" is selected, which is also the recommended security setting, after some time it reverts to "Notify me to install updates".

For me the desired state is that the setting "Allow Adobe to install updates" remains. The alternative setting of "Notify me to install updates" can be a security risk because such an update message can also be feigned by malware, which has occurred in the past (e.g. Flashback).

I have repeatedly tried resetting it to the desired "Allow Adobe to install updates", but again after some time (after a few days of computer use and/r reboots) the setting returns to "Notify me to install updates".

The only thing the Macs (various iMacs and MacBooks) running with this bug have in common was that they are running Mac OS X 10.11.x El Capitan.

How can I prevent this buggy setting change, and is it caused by malware, since administrator rights are required to change this setting?

Answer (score 0):

Tried uninstall and reinstall the latest version seems fix the issue.

Comment: yes but only temporarily :-(

Comment: We can keep the "Allow Adobe to install updates" selections for at least 3 days.

PS: You have to completely uninstall and then install the latest version download from Adobe.